# Installing a Linux kernel in the UEFI BIOS of the Xiaomi Mi Air 13

Tags: linux, bios, uefi, gentoo, secure-boot

My post is about the UEFI BIOS of the  Xiaomi Mi Air 13. It is a very interesting laptop, light and tough. His BIOS seems an InsydeH20 One, and I can't clear Secure Boot keys.

I'm in the process to install my homemade linux kernel inside the UEFI memory to boot my Gentoo Linux as shown here: [Excellent LInux UEFI Howto](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide) 
To explicitly integrate the Linux kernel in secure mode, I need to:
1- Backup the active keys (Ok, done.) I have them, Microsoft, mostly.
2- Erase en existing keys (seems buggy)
3- Write back Microsoft keys, and mine, to get my Linux kernel spoted secure and boot fluently.

At this moment, everything is fine, unless the ability to Clear Secure Boot Keys.

- First, to disable Secure boot, I had to create a BIOS admin password. Done.
- Then, I can disable Secure Boot. Done
- Then, I can see my UEFI USB key to boot, and I can start Linux.

Now, I just want to erase and write back the Secure Boot Keys, and therefore I pulse the adequate "Clear Secure Boot Keys" in the BIOS, whose help show :
"Force System to Setup Mode at next boot. System boots without any Secure Boot keys"
Unfortunately, these keys are still there, even after trying to boot without them; reboot after reboot.

Is this a BIOS bug?
How could I more precisely clear these keys?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not familiar with that computer or its firmware, but from your description, it may be a bug. It could also be you're doing something subtly wrong. You might look for a firmware update and, if the problem persists after updating (or if there is no update), contact the manufacturer or ask for help on a manufacturer-specific forum. Unfortunately, there are a lot of EFI bugs out there, and they tend to vary a lot from one machine to another, so when you deal with bugs, it's often things that are very machine-specific.